# Running a macro (with arguments) in CATIA V5 from Python

Tags: python, vba, catia

Although this solution
([Run a Catia macro with a python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34833407/run-a-catia-macro-with-a-python-script)) works well for macros that runs without arguments, my problem starts at the moment I need to pass something from python to the vba macro in CATIA.

Currently my test macro in CATIA looks like that:

```vb
Sub CATMain(name As String)
    MsgBox "Hi!" & " " & name
End Sub
```

How to pass the neccessary argument "name" from python in order to execute this macro properly?

Comment: I suggest du use _ExecuteScript_ instead of a _StartCommand_ (see also doumentation). There you can define parameters.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/55844649/17172829

Answer (score 0):

---

That's my implementation to solve this problem...

```py
import win32com.client

def execute_macro(mod_name:str, function_name:str, parameters:list)->None:
    library_name = "C:\\files\\catia\\macros\\macros-set.catvba" #Absolute path
    library_type = 2  # for catScriptLibraryTypeVBAProject type

    try:
        catia = win32com.client.Dispatch("CATIA.Application")
        catia.SystemService.ExecuteScript(library_name, library_type, mod_name, function_name, parameters)
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error on execute:", str(e))
        return False
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).